# Initializing map elements, where value is a struct with mutex lock golang

Tags: go, synchronization

I have a map where every value is a pointer to another struct that itself has a lock.

```
type StatMap map[string]*Stats

type Stats struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    someStats, someMoreStats float64
}
```

I have implemented a method where I pack the StatMap into another struct and have a Mutex lock for the entire map, but I am expecting to modify every entry in the map simoultaniously from hundreds of goroutines, so it would be more effective to lock every element in the map so that two or more goroutines can read and modify values for entries in parallell.

What I am wondering is how I can initialize a new entry in the map whenever there comes a new key? I cannot lock the entry if it isn't in the map already, and I cannot check if it is in the map (as far as I know) in case another goroutine is currently modifying that entry.

I do not know what keys will be in the map before runtime.

My current implementation (that causes data races):

```
initializeStatMap("key")
statMap["key"].Lock()
// . . . 


func initializeStatMap(key string) {
    if statMap[key] != nil {
        return
    }
    statMap[key] = &Stats{someStats: 0, someMoreStats: 0}
}
```

Comment: Regular maps are not safe to write concurrently (as you seem to know). In the 1.9 release there is a concurrent map in `sync.Map`. You might use that to make sure you don't have a race condition on write. That said, with each item having a mutex, you only need to worry about adding a new item. You could have a mutex just for adding to the map with a double check after obtaining the lock to make sure you don't add the same item.

Comment: Locking your map and locking bunch of structs in the map are 2 different activities. When you are doing any changes to the map itself you need to lock/unlock every reads/writes/deletes of the map. When you locking/unlocking your structs that are inside the map this activity is separate from locking your map.

Comment: I forget that maps also cannot be concurrently read if another routine is writing. A write could trigger a rebuild of the underlying buckets, causing a read to go awry. Just use `sync.Map`.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: "Just use sync.Map." Read the instructions before using.  "It is optimized for use in concurrent loops with keys that are stable over time, and either few steady-state stores, or stores localized to one goroutine per key. For use cases that do not share these attributes, it will likely have comparable or worse performance and worse type safety than an ordinary map paired with a read-write mutex." [sync.Map](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map)

Comment: @peterSO sorry, it's late, I forgot to add to my comment that using sync.Map is the easiest way to not mess it up accidentally, as is so easily done when dealing with concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go's map semantics are as follows:

- A map stores *values* (not variables) and that's why these values are
  not adressable, and that's why you can't do something like

  ```
  type T struct {
      X int
  }
  m := make(map[int]T)
  m[0] = T{}
  m[0].x = 42 // won't compile
  ```
- This requirement mostly comes from from the fact a map, being
  an intricate dynamic data structure, should allow its particular
  implementations to physically *move* the values it contains
  around in memory — when doing rebalancing etc.

That's why the only three operations a map supports is adding
(or replacing) of its elements, getting them back and deleting them.

A map is not safe for concurrent use, so in order to do any of those three
operations on the same map concurrently, you need to protect it in
one way or another.

Consequently, once you have read a value from a map, orchestrating
concurrent access to *it* is a completely another story,
and here we're facing another fact about the map's semantics:
since it keeps values and is free to *copy* them around in memory,
it's not allowed to keep in a map anything which you want to have
reference semantics. For instance, it would be incorrect to keep values
of your `Stats` type in the map directly—because they embed instances
of `sync.Mutex`, and copying of them prohibited after they are first used.
Here you're already doing the right thing by storing pointers to your
variables.

Now you can see that it's pretty OK to roll like this:

1. Access the map itself to get a value bound to a key in a concurrent-safe
   way (say, by holding a lock).
2. Lock the mutex on that variable and operate on it. That does not
   involve the map at all.

The only remaining possible problem is as follows.
Suppose you're protecting the access to your map with a lock.
So you grab the lock, obtain the value bound to a key, *by copying
it to a variable,* release the lock and work with the copy of the
value.

Now while you're working with the copy of that value another
goroutine is free to update the map by deleting the value or replacing it.

While in your case it's fine technically — because your map operates on
pointers to variables, and it's fine to copy pointers — this might be inappropriate from the standpoint of the semantics of your program,
and this is something you have to think through.
To make it more clear, once you've got a pointer to some instance of `Stats`
and locked *it,* a pointer to this instance can be removed from the map,
or the map entry which held it could be updated by another pointer —
pointing to another instance of `Stats`, so once you're done with the
instance, it might have become unreachable via the map.